# Calculate the ratio(i.e sum(numerator)/(Denominator)) for latest 3 weeks,Have to use Groupby Id,year,week and sort by year and week

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
    Id  Year  Week  numerator  Denominator
0    1  2018    21       1        1
1    1  2018    22       1        0
2    1  2018    34       1        1
3    1  2018    35       1        1
4    1  2018    36       1        0
5    1  2018    42       1        0
6    1  2019     2       1        0
7    1  2019     3       1        1
8    1  2019     5       1        1
9    2  2018    40       1        0
10   2  2018    43       1        1
11   2  2018    44       1        1
12   2  2019     2       1        0
13   2  2019     3       1        1
14   3  2018    50       1        1
15   3  2018    52       1        0
16   3  2019     1       1        1
```

output

```
6    1  2019     2       1        0   (3/2)
7    1  2019     3       1        1   (3/2) 
8    1  2019     5       1        1    (3/2)
13   2  2019     3       1        1    (2/1)
12   2  2019     2       1        0    (2/1)
11   2  2018    44       1        1      1
```

after adding numerator and denominator ratio will be added to ratio

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: @jezrael edited

Comment: n=3                       
  df.sort_values(['Year','week'],ascending=False).groupby('Id').head(n)                                    After sorting this i have to add all of these numerator and denominator and calculate the ratio

Comment: One thing - why is first group sort like `2,3,5` and second like `3,2`?

Comment: @jezrael for second one also i mentioned output as 3,2,44 because i want 3 latest weeks

Comment: @jezrael thanks will ping u if anything needed

Comment: yop, because I was surprise first group is sorted `2,3,5` (ascending) amd second group is descending `3,2`. So correct is `5,3,2` and `3,2,44`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206684/discussion-between-rakesh-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with 3 columns and [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html), for `ratio` use grouping by 2 columns with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['Id','Year','Week'],ascending=[True,False, False]).groupby('Id').head(3)
df1['ratio'] = df1.groupby(['Id','Year']).transform('sum').eval('numerator/Denominator')
print (df1)
    Id  Year  Week  numerator  Denominator  ratio
8    1  2019     5          1            1    1.5
7    1  2019     3          1            1    1.5
6    1  2019     2          1            0    1.5
13   2  2019     3          1            1    2.0
12   2  2019     2          1            0    2.0
11   2  2018    44          1            1    1.0
16   3  2019     1          1            1    1.0
15   3  2018    52          1            0    2.0
14   3  2018    50          1            1    2.0
```